# Multiplexing TLS and plain on one port

Tags: tls

I have a service that runs HTTPS and XMPP multiplexed on a single port. The HTTPS part of the service always uses implicit TLS, but the XMPP protocol may use implicit TLS or may negotiate TLS after a handshake with the StartTLS command.

I had originally set aside two ports (one for HTTPS/XMPP with implicit TLS and one for XMPP with StartTLS) but eventually decided that I could multiplex everything over a single port by peeking at the first byte of the TCP buffer and seeing if it was `\x16` and if so performing the TLS handshake and if not if it was `<` meaning it's an XMPP handshake and we'll need to enforce StartTLS as the first step. Since the first byte in an HTTP connection would be a printable ASCII character (so not `\x16`) we could detect that too at a later date if we needed to offer plain HTTP for some reason.

Is there some reason not to do this (other than some potential future TLS or TLS-like security later possibly not starting with `\x16`)? My intuition tells me it's wrong but the worst I can think of that could happen is an accidental TLS detection when the user didn't intend TLS (in which case TLS / the connection would fail, which is fine).

Comment: It does sound brittle like you mentioned. Also, what are you gaining out of this multiplexing?

Comment: Also, you might get better answers to this on stack overflow instead of here.

Comment: The application will be running in a very constrained environment where the only port allowed by an overzealous corporate firewall is 443 (or maybe 80, we'll see; doesn't really matter, point is they may refuse to give us two ports). However, since this isn't common I'm concerned about the security implications of doing so (if any).

Comment: Nginx can do the TLS detection for you: https://www.nginx.com/blog/running-non-ssl-protocols-over-ssl-port-nginx-1-15-2/

Comment: I'm not using nginx, but I guess this does indicate that it's not a terrible idea. Out of curiosity, for people voting to close, what isn't clear or what guideline does it violate? I re-read the question and it seems clear, but if I'm missing anything I'd be happy to clarify. Also I re-read the rules and it seems like it fits?